# 4 Brachos once?

Tags: blessing, riddle

Which four brachos are said exactly once every year outside of Israel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this question is restricted to outside of israel is becuase three special berachot in the seder are said once a year in Eretz Yisrael, and twice a year outside of Israel:

- Ga'al Yisrael
- Al achilat matzah
- Al achilat maror.

Comment: And Kiddush for Shavuot, Sukkot and Shemini Atzeret.

Answer (score 5):

1)Seeing the first blossoms in the spring (OC 226:1).

2)Bedikas chametz (OC 432:1).

3)The special bracha of "Nachem" during the Mincha Amida of Tisha B'Av (OC 557:1).

4)Lighting candles on erev Yom Kippur (OC 610:2, AS 296).

Comment: #3 is not true in many sephardi minhagim -- we say Nachem during Arvit and Shacharit as well.

Comment: Here's a fifth: The brocha of Kedushas Hayom in Yom Kippur Musaf.

Comment: @AY: I was considering that, but decided against it as it has the same chatima as the beracha of kedushat hayom in the other tefillot