# Which Brachas are said only once a year?

Tags: halacha, blessing, calendar

I am looking for a list of Berachos/blessings that are recited a maximum of once per year.

Which blessings (from prayer, Jewish rituals, or otherwise, by men or women) are recited only once per year?  Additionally, which ones **can** be recited up to once per year, but are not required to be made yearly?

Comment: I'm not sure these would count: the bracha of L'hachniso at a brit said by a father and Al Pidyon haben (because I assume that a man wouldn't have more than one male child in a calendar year in a monogamous relationship, though I guess he could say it, get divorced, get remarried and have another child within the year) and if one says a single bracha over ALL his trumat ma'aser (not species by species) at one time, then L'hafrish trumot. Same with Lifdot Ma'aser sheini. All guesses...

Comment: In view of above comment, please specify in your question if you mean brachot that are said by EVERYONE once yearly, no matter what, or brachot that might happen to occur once per year for a specific person depending on circumstances, such as those mentioned above, a marriage. I also assume that you are excluding *Birkat Hachama* which would happen once in the specific year that it needs to be said.

Comment: You’ve tagged this as [tag:riddle], whose tag info literally says not to use it as if it’s a suitable tag the question will be closed as off-topic. If you’re curious or want to join the discussion, the relevant meta post is [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139/riddle-questions-on-se).

Comment: @doniel I tagged it thusly

Comment: Apologies to all , I didn't know the riddle rule.

Comment: @rosends I have a relative who had 2 children in the same calendar year (although it was a non-Jewish year) with the same wife, one in January, one in December, so Milah Brachos can be said twice in one year even in regular circumstances.  Techincally, the maximum for all of the Brachos you mentioned is more than 1, so they would not count according to my question.

Comment: Would there be any way for this to be reworded as a non-"Riddle"? I do want to know the answer to this, and I do not currently know it.  I am not in any way  filling the definition of the meta post listed above: "With riddles, the asker makes an effort to conceal relevant information, to keep the answer from being obvious.".  It is simply information I am asking others to help me find.  Comparing it to other questions with riddle tags, it does not seem to fit in. Cont...

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to fit a regular (outside of MY) riddle definition: "a question or statement intentionally phrased so as to require ingenuity in ascertaining its answer or meaning, typically presented as a game."  Feel free to forward this to Meta if the discussion does not belong here, I'm not sure yet of the actual delineation of what can be a comment on a post vs. what should be a meta question.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What about blessings said twice every 9 years? Or 5 times every 2 years?

Comment: @DoubleAA the same could be asked for many questions on this site.  But in this case, it is essentially an interesting conversation to learn the Halachos of some of them, and to bring up Shailos about them, such as if your discussion of Birkas HaIlanos - is it something said on an experience that happens once a year, but if it happens twice, it can be recited, or is it a beracha that can only be said once a year period?  But it leads to Talmud Torah nevertheless, it's interesting, and it falls into an allowable category of questions.  כנלע"ד.

Comment: @DoubleAA and if we're being super technical, I could say that I am a Rebbi  looking for riddles to use with Talmidim, but I don't know them yet, so it still doesn't fit the MY definition of a riddle, even if that is the final outcome. But I prefer the above.

Comment: @DoubleAA At the end of the day, if you feel it appropriate to close, please do so.  You are the moderator, and it's your discretion.  I would hold nothing against you, even though I personally think it should be open.  (Also, I got some excellent answers already, and a lot to think and talk about. )

Comment: I’m not sure why this was reopened. Seemingly the same problems that got it closed in the first place remain - the main text was never edited.

Comment: @DonielF I argued (and the community clearly agreed by reopening it) that this fell outside the regular riddle parameters, as you can read in the comments above.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/4-brachos-once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a M.Y. answer on this one - a hunch.

Two that occur to me offhand are:

The bracha for lighting candles before Yom Kippur    .להדליק נר של יום הכפורים

ברכת האלנות - The bracha upon seeing fruits bloom on a fruity tree may be said only once yearly. I'll add in halachic source, later.

I got these from a yeshivanews.com page:

על ביעור חמץ upon inspecting for chametz.

נחם ציון ובונה ירושלים said on Tish'a B'Av

(Thanks to DoubleAA for the help on these two:)

It is possible to say the bracha for Eruv Tavshilin just once per year, such as this year (5779) when 7th day of Pesach is on Friday, in Diaspora.

In Israel, it could occur **either** when 7th day of Pesach is on Friday or the 1st day of Shavuot is on Friday, or the 1st day Rosh Hashannah is on Thursday.

It is possible to say המבדיל בן קודש לקודש once per year, also. This occurs only in Israel when either the 1st day of Pesach is on Sunday or the 1st day of Shavuot is on Sunday.

Comment: Not everyone says a blessing when lighting candles for Yom Kippur. Also arguably if you move to Australia from Canada in August you could say the blessing on blossoming trees twice in the same year.

Comment: What about the final bracha on the haftara of Yom Kippur morning?

Comment: @JoelK Nope. That same bracha is used during all the tefillot of Shemoneh Esreh on Yom Kippur. It's a good attempt, though.

Comment: It depends how you define a bracha. The end (from baruch ata Hashem) may be the same as in the amidah, but the beginning (al hatorah etc) is certainly different

Comment: The chazzan says נחם twice.  Also, if you're only counting brachot as unique based on the chatima, if you have to eat and you eat bread and bentch you might say it (although if you say ברחמיו in bentching it would be different).

Comment: @Heshy If saying מנחם ציון you don't say ברחמיו too. But notably you could say that blessing all year in a mourner's house. (And of course some communities recite Nachem at all services on Tisha Bav.)

Comment: The Beracha on Shofar is sometimes said only once per year

Answer (score 5):

[R. Yosef Qafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) (Note 34 to Chapter 10 of Hilchos Berachos) understood R. Saadia Gaon to be of the opinion that the Blessing of the Sun is recited once per year.

> ונראה כי לפני רס"ג היה רק עד עושה בראשית ומן ואימת הוי עד הסוף לא היה
>   ולפיכך כתב בסדורו עמ' צ ועל השמש ביום תקופת תמוז יברך עושה בראשית
>   **וברור כי הכוונה בכל שנה ושנה** וכך האמור בברייתא לבנה בגבורתה הכוונה
>   בהתחדשה והיא ברכת הירח שבכל חדש

Comment: As usual, fantastic answer! +1.

Comment: The blessing is said multiple times a year. This one stimulus for it only happens once a year, but so what? This would be like answering that Lihadlik Ner Shel Yom Tov for Shavuot is only said once a year even though it's also said on other occasions.

Comment: @DoubleAA Now that you make that point, I agree.  I hadn't noticed that when I originally read it, only later.  I'm not sure I would remove it as an answer, but I would remove my upvote for this answer if I could (it's locked for me since it hasn't been edited).

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Was the question asking what texts can only be recited once per year, or what beracha-inducing-phenomena can only occur once per year?

Comment: @Alex The question says "Berachos/blessings that are recited a maximum of once per year".  I still appreciate your research, though.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Interestingly, in *Contemporary Halakhic Problems* vol. II R. Bleich argues that the עושה מעשה בראשית of Birchas Hachamah is fundamentally different from the עושה מעשה בראשית of other phenomena. [Link](https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems%2C_Vol_II%2C_Part_I%2C_Chapter_II_Blessings_and_Rituals.51?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Answer (score 4):

If you live in Eretz Yisrael, all of the brachos unique to the Seder (i.e. אשר גאלנו at the end of Maggid, על אכילת מצה, and על אכילת מרור) are only said once a year.

Comment: Depending on time and place shofar and lulav would be the same.

Comment: @Alex In what case is the bracha on lulav only made once a year? While Shofar could be made once a year if RH falls out on Shabbos, the OP wanted brachos which can never be made more than once per year.

Comment: According to Torah law both shofar and lulav (in most places) are only for one day. Thus, if you live before any takanos were made ("Depending on **time** and place")  you would only make a berachah once a year.

Answer (score 3):

There is an obligation to donate a half shekel once per year:

**[Rambam Hilchot Shekalim Introduction & 1:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=18&perek=1&hilite=)**

> מצות עשה אחת והיא ליתן כל איש מחצית השקל בכל שנה וביאור מצוה זו בפרקים
>   אלו
>
> מצות עשה מן התורה ליתן כל איש מישראל מחצית השקל בכל שנה ושנה אפילו עני
>   המתפרנס מן הצדקה חייב ושואל מאחרים או מוכר כסות שעל כתיפו ונותן מחצית
>   השקל כסף שנאמר העשיר לא ירבה והדל לא ימעיט וגו' ואינו נותנו בפעמים
>   רבות היום מעט ולמחר מעט אלא נותנו כולו כאחת בפעם אחת
>
> It contains one positive commandment: [The obligation] that every man
>   give a half-shekel [to the Temple treasury] every year. This mitzvah
>   is explained in the [following] chapters.
>
> It is a positive commandment from the Torah that every adult Jewish
>   male give a half-shekel each and every year. Even a poor man who
>   derives his livelihood from charity is obligated [to make this
>   donation]. He should borrow from others or sell the clothes he is
>   wearing so that he can give a half-shekel of silver, as [Exodus 30:15]
>   states: "The rich shall not give more, nor should the poor give
>   less."
>
> [The half-shekel] should not be given in several partial payments -
>   today a portion, tomorrow a portion. Instead, it is to be given all at
>   once. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946889/jewish/Shekalim-Chapter-One.htm))

[R. Yehuda Ben Yakar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Yakar) writes that a beracha is made on this mitzvah:

**Peirush Hatefilot V'Haberachot Vol. II p. 73**

> ונראה כמו כן בזמן שהיה בית המקדש קיים והיו נותנין מחצית השקל היו
>   מברכין אקב"ו לתת מחצית השקל

Answer (score 0):

One that has not been mentioned so far is the brachah on rain. The gemara Taanit 6 discusses a unique brakhah recited over the first rainfall of the year or first rainfall after a drought. Shulchan Arukh Orach Chaim 221 codifies that it is only said after a drought; the poskim debate whether this would apply to Israel every year or only an unusual drought (see Mishnah Berurah and Biur Halachah there). At least according to some shitot, this is recited once a year under normal conditions in Israel.

I had once heard a version of OP's question as a riddle that there were 4 brachot recited once a year every year for Jews everywhere in the world. The best I have come up with so far is these, which have been mentioned so far:
Birkat hailanot
Biur hametz
Ner yom hakippurim
Though as DoubleAA points out this might not be true for everyone in all circumstances. Likewise, I would point out that there may be circumstances where one says al biur hametz twice. See Mishnah Berurah432:5 & 7.

I suspect nachem might have been intended as the 4th, but (1) Sephardim say nachem more than once and (2) the chazan says nachem twice (as Heshy pointed out).